# Updated global variable not being passed into String

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm getting this issue where I try to set a global variable inside a function and use a globally declared string with concatenation of the said variable.

When checked inside the method, the variable has been set correctly, but it's not detected in the concatenated String.
What could be the reasoning behind this.

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const express = require('express');

let environment;
let myUrl = `https://ets-tst-${environment}.mydomain.com/health`

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    environment= 'dev'
    console.log(environment)  //prints dev
    console.log(myUrl) //prints https://ets-tst-undefined.mydomain.com/health
});
```

Comment: Do you expect that this concatenated string somehow magically updates? Thats not how it works. at `let environment;` its set to undefined by default. You need to set your url AFTER you assigned a value to `environment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in Mohamad answer you set `environment` after `myUrl` so when `myUrl` is evaluated `environment` is currently undefined.

However if you want to dynamically change `myUrl` you could do like so:

```
let environment;
let myUrl = (env) => `https://ets-tst-${env}.mydomain.com/health`

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    environment= 'dev'

    console.log(environment)  //prints dev
    console.log(myUrl(environment)) //prints https://ets-tst-dev.mydomain.com/health
});
```

Here myUrl is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that takes an `env` string as param and returns the formatted url. Because now the formatted url string is evaluated when `myUrl()` arrow function is called!

You could also do:

```
let environment;
let myUrl = () => `https://ets-tst-${environment}.mydomain.com/health`

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    environment= 'dev'

    console.log(environment)  //prints dev
    console.log(myUrl()) //prints https://ets-tst-dev.mydomain.com/health
}
```

Here you don't have to pass `env` param because when `myUrl` is called it gonna read the current value of `environment` which has been updated to `'dev'` right above.

But I wouldn't recommand that because reading a global variable to create the string in that case could lead to unwanted behaviors if you don't keep track of the updates of `environment` var.
This is called a 'side-effect' and you should avoid it as described [here](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#avoid-side-effects-part-1)

Answer (score 2):

you set `environment` after `myUrl` you can't set value in variable
you can set before this like:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const express = require('express');

let environment = 'dev';
let myUrl = `https://ets-tst-${environment}.mydomain.com/health`

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    console.log(environment)  //prints dev
    console.log(myUrl) //prints https://ets-tst-undefined.mydomain.com/health
});
```

Comment: right. I was thinking I could dynamically change `environment= 'dev' `, 'nft' etc  inside different functions, using the same `myUrl` variable and setting `environment` variable inside different functions accordingly. It seems not possible looking at this.